# How to process a Java List (sent from Java programs) in a Python function?

Tags: java, python

I have a Java List like shows here in the following Java code block:

```
List<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();
list.add(1.2345);
list.add(2.2345);
```

Then I have passed this list to a parameter of a Python function within a Python program like here shows:

```
def JListPrcessor(javalist):
    print "pass the processor"
    javalist = list(javalist)
    print javalist
```

But some errors happened while the program was running, and the `JListPrcessor` just didn't print anything out.

I don't know if it's possible to do the argument passing of List type from Java to Python, or if there will be another way to do it? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: "some errors happened" What errors???

Comment: Traceback ? Module used for connecting java to python ? Errors ?

Comment: I'd guess Jython is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass an `ArrayList` to a Python script, so you would have to turn your `ArrayList` into a string like so:

```
public static String listToString(List<Object> list)
{
    String listConcat = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        String num = String.valueOf(list.get(i));
        if((i + 1) != list.size())
        {
            listConcat += num + ",";
        }
        else
        {
            listConcat += num;
        }
    }
    return listConcat;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(1.2345);
    list.add(2.2345);
    System.out.println(listToString(list));
}
```

Next, you would have to call the Python script from your Java program with the ArrayList String as a command line argument, so you would call it like:

```
python foo.py "1.2345,2.2345"
```

Then in `foo.py`, you have to split the string at the comma and convert each string to a float:

```
import sys

def JListPrcessor(javalist):
    print "pass the processor"
    jlist = [float(num) for num in javalist.split(",")]
    print jlist

try:
    inputList = sys.argv[1]
except:
    print "No input str given"
    sys.exit(1)

JListPrcessor(inputList)
```

Which gives:

```
pass the processor
[1.2345, 2.2345]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are doing, but if you are having modules built in different languages, why not use a format in between that can be understood? You can change your list to JSON for example, using existing libraries, and then on your python side, parse that JSON back to a python dict. This should not require any effort from your side if you don't sent too complicated objects.